# TYPO3 only one file in fe_manager

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18 and extension fe_manager. User profile has a field image. How to allow to upload only one image ? And if user upload new image, old image must be replacing with new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just add `'maxitems' => 1` in your fileds image TCA configuration.